# Supremum on $[0,T]\times A$ for $A$ compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let $f:[0,T]\times A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Is it true that
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \lVert f(t) \rVert_{C(A)} = \lVert f\rVert_{C([0,T]\times A)}?$$
i.e.,
$$\sup_{t \in [0,T]}\sup_{x \in A} |f(t)(x)| = \sup_{(x,t) \in [0,T] \times A}|f(t)(x)|$$
?
Isn't the first equality on the left hand side the same as $\lVert f \rVert_{C([0,T];C(A))}$?

I think this equality does not hold when $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first claim is true, if I'm not mistaken. Denote $l = \sup_{t\in[0,T]} \sup_{x\in A} \lvert f(t)(x) \rvert$ and $r = \sup_{(x,t) \in [0,T] \times A} \lvert f(t)(x) \rvert$. For any $a < b < l$, there is a $t\in[0,T]$ such that $\sup_{x\in A} \lvert f(t)(x) \rvert > b$, so that there is also an $x \in A$ such that $f(t)(x) > a$. Therefore, $r \geq l$. You can similarly prove that $l \geq r$. Therefore, $l = r$.

The second claim is correct as well.

Comment: As for the last claim, can you clarify which equality you mean? If you're referring to your first equation, the sup norm is not well-defined on $C(A)$ when $A$ is not compact. On the other hand, your second equation would still be true, because I never used compactness in my proof above. Only the order and completeness properties of the codomain mattered.

Comment: Thanks for answering. but now I'm confused, I thought my first and second displayed equations were equivalent. Aren't they?

Comment: It's a technicality that arises from the fact that norms have to be finite, but supremums can be infinite. The first displayed equation assumes that there is a norm on the spaces, while the second doesn't. When $A$ is compact, the continuous functions on the relevant spaces are bounded, so that the function spaces $C$ can be given the sup norm. However, if $A$ is not compact, then continuous functions need not be bounded (think $\tan$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$). If we try to define a sup norm on $C(A)$ in the latter case, some elements may have infinite "norm", which isn't allowed.

Comment: We could also consider only the bounded continuous functions, the space of which is often denoted $BC$. This space is *always* normable with the sup norm.

Comment: ah, I understand. Thanks.